# OCGX and hyperref: visibility and clickability of overlapping links

Tags: hyperref, ocg, ocgx

I am using `ocgx` to display different text blocks (in the same area of the same page) upon clicking links in the PDF.

However, each of these textblocks has its own `\href` links, and these links overlap on the page (concealing earlier-defined OCGs) even when no text is visible(!). Is it possible to make an `ocg` toggle not just visibility, but also layer ordering?

In the MWE below, note that toggling the textblock visibility with buttons 1,2 *does not* toggle the presence of href links, and only the link "google.com" is present, even when neither ocg is visible (mouse pointer not captured in my screenshots)....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{12pt}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{12pt}

\begin{document}
\actionsocg{ocg1}{}{ocg2}{{\color{blue}{button 1}}}$|$ %toggle ocg1, hide ocg2
\actionsocg{ocg2}{}{ocg1}{{\color{blue}{button 2}}}%toggle ocg2, hide ocg1

%define OCGs:
  \begin{ocg}{}{ocg1}{0}
    \begin{textblock}{40}(1,1)
      \href{http://overleaf.com}{Link 1}
    \end{textblock}
  \end{ocg}

  \begin{ocg}{}{ocg2}{0}
    \begin{textblock}{40}(1,1)
      \href{http://google.com}{Link 2}    
    \end{textblock}
  \end{ocg}

\end{document}
```

[image: mouse over link after pressing button 1]
[image: mouse over link after pressing button 1]

Comment: +1 Very good question!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21717943/3384763

Comment: The question is certainly a good question since Paul Gaborit, ocgx maintainer, says so. However, I did not understand the problem. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @AndréC Updated w/ mouseover screenshots (pointer not visible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with package **`ocgx2`** plus patching `hyperref` a bit to make it PDF layer-aware.

Note however that only Acrobat Reader respects the visibility of links that are placed on PDF layers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%patch hyperref to make PDF Annotations PDF-Layer-(OCG)-aware
\makeatletter
  \let\Hy@setpdfborderOrig\Hy@setpdfborder
  \def\Hy@setpdfborder{\ocgbase@insert@oc\Hy@setpdfborderOrig}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{12pt}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{12pt}

\begin{document}
\actionsocg{ocg1}{}{ocg2}{{\color{blue}{button 1}}}$|$ %toggle ocg1, hide ocg2
\actionsocg{ocg2}{}{ocg1}{{\color{blue}{button 2}}}%toggle ocg2, hide ocg1

%define OCGs:
  \begin{ocg}{}{ocg1}{0}
    \begin{textblock}{40}(1,1)
      \href{http://overleaf.com}{Link 1}
    \end{textblock}
  \end{ocg}

  \begin{ocg}{}{ocg2}{0}
    \begin{textblock}{40}(1,1)
      \href{http://google.com}{Link 2}
    \end{textblock}
  \end{ocg}

\end{document}
```

Creating switches for mutually concealing PDF layers by means of `\actionsocg` quickly gets cumbersome if the number of PDF layers increases. In order to simplify, pkg **`ocgx2`** allows OCGs to be grouped into **Radio Button Groups**. From all OCGs belonging to the same Radio Button Group only one can be enabled at a time, automatically hiding the previously visible OCG. An OCG is added to a Radio Button Group with option `radiobtngrp=...`. Grouping OCGs into a Radio Button Group allows us to use the simple `\showocg` command to create switches for every layer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%patch hyperref to make PDF Annotations PDF-Layer-(OCG)-aware
\makeatletter
  \let\Hy@setpdfborderOrig\Hy@setpdfborder
  \def\Hy@setpdfborder{\ocgbase@insert@oc\Hy@setpdfborderOrig}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{fontawesome,pgffor}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\foreach \ocgname / \urlicon in {%
  GitHub/\faGithub, StackExchange/\faStackExchange, StackOverflow/\faStackOverflow, Google/\faGoogle% 
}{\showocg{\ocgname}{\urlicon}\ }\\[1ex]
%define OCGs, within the same Radio Button Group
\foreach \ocgname / \weburl in {%
  GitHub/{https://github.com}, StackExchange/{https://stackexchange.com}, StackOverflow/{https://stackoverflow.com}, Google/{https://google.com}%
}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=myURLs]{\ocgname}{\ocgname}{off}
    \url{\weburl}
  \end{ocg}}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One word: bravo!

Comment: @AndréC :-) approved also for me. :-).

Comment: @Ian It can be further simplified using a Radio Button Group. I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: @IanAppelbaum Ok. Done.

Comment: @ALexG Does your method still work with Adobe Reader? Here, using `evince` as a PDF viewer, the links are not correct (even if the hyperref frames are hiding/showing well).

Comment: @Paul Unfortunately, among the PDF viewers with OCG support only Acrobat Reader correctly acknowledges the visibility of links that are placed on PDF Layers. And, as shown in the answer, it requires some preparation for the links to be associated with OCGs. The link annotation needs an `/OC <ocg/ocmd reference>` entry in its dictionary (while the link text as part of the page content stream is already placed on the OCG) .