# OCGX Overlapping Links Visibility

Tags: hyperref, ocg, ocgx2, ocgx

I'm using OCGX to generate multiple layers with text and links. All layers are set invisible/hidden (0) by default, except one "main" visible layer. The purpose of this is so when the PDF is opened in some non-layer compatible PDF viewers (such as Apple's Preview), the "main" layer will still show some necessary or essential content.
This works fine so far, the issue is that links in hidden layers still "permeate" through. The text is invisible, but the link remains active. Hovering over with the mouse will toggle to the link-pointer and clicking will direct me to the URL. This also means that some non-hyperlinked text from the main layer will appear as if it was linking to something, but it's just the underlying links showing.

Is there a way to completely turn off links in hidden layers as to avoid the above issue? Other than not linking, of course.

I looked at this, but doesn't seem to workout/address the issue I'm raising: [OCGX and hyperref: visibility and clickability of overlapping links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477878/ocgx-and-hyperref-visibility-and-clickability-of-overlapping-links)

Thx

Comment: Which PDF viewers are you testing with? Try with Adobe Reader.

Comment: Adobe Reader and Preview.Adobe Reader works fine, but what I need is for hidden links not to "show" in Preview (I would call them ghost links since they show no text).

Comment: Preview (from Apple) and many other PDF viewers (like `evince` in Linux) are not fully or not at all compatible with OCGs. Unfortunately, there is no way around these limits...

Comment: @Paul You could add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Preview` (from Apple) and many other PDF viewers (like `evince` in Linux) are not fully or not at all compatible with OCGs. Unfortunately, there is no way around these limits...